# Supply word alternative

Tags: word-choice

I am rewriting existing documentation and there is a photo of mobile device with an arrow to micro-USB port and a description "Supply Micro USB". Another arrow is titled "Supply indicator". I do not like this description. Is it correct or not? I know a term "power supply" but I would prefer "Charge". What would native speaker use?

Answer (score 2):

We would call it a **charger port**. If we had to specify, it would be a **Micro USB charger port**.